# how to design two buttons overlap on screen with opacity flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to show to buttons which are overlap on main screen when we onPressed on add button. Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a stack and add buttons in it

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  bool showPopUp = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text("Open pop up"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    showPopUp = true;
                  });
                },
              )),
            ),
            if (showPopUp)
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      showPopUp = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text("add container"),
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text("add container 2"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]